# Remove first element of a string list

Tags: haskell

I am trying to remove the first element of a string list in Haskell so for example:
["String1", "String2", "String3"] -> ["String2", "String3"]
["Red", "Yellow", "Orange", "Blue"] - > ["Yellow", "Orange", "Blue"]

I attempted to solve the problem by going:

```
removeFirst :: [String] -> [String]
removeFirst [] = []
removeFirst [h:t] = t
removeFirst _ = []
```

It gives me the following errors:

```
Couldn't match type ‘Char’ with ‘[Char]’
  Expected: [String]
    Actual: [Char]
```

How would I implement this so it does not give me errors?

Comment: `removeFirst (h:t) = t`

Answer (score 0):

Please allow me to share my way of finding the solution of this question.

1. I will go to  [hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org)
2. Then I will try to check the most general type of the function that I'm looking for. In This case, we have `[String] -> [String]`, so we can generalize it into `[a] -> [a]`
3. Put it in the search query.
4. Voila... we got several possible answer.
5. And in my result, I got `tail` at the top, and when I check it, I see it as the correct answer.

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:tail